# Cannot access already opened Files

Tags: unity, 15.10

I am a new user to Ubuntu from Windows. I have a bit of a weird bug on my Ubuntu 15.10. It seems to happen randomly, as I cannot reproduce it at will.

I have a few applications open and maximised such as Firefox, files, etc.

When I want to access my already opened Files, it doesn't revert to the windows already opened when I click on the Files icon on the launcher, instead it opens a brand new File window! It seems to be happening more often with Files. I always have to frustratingly minimise all other windows.

I am wondering if anyone else encountered this, and if there is a fix to this? Thank you.

Comment: This is a real bug I am waiting for a fix from a long time..
You can reproduce it : Open Files--> mount and navigate to any partition-->minimize it --> now click on Files--> you get a new window